# How to prioritize Laravel custom validation rule over defaults

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a custom validation rule

```
'title' => ['required', 'min:3', 'unique:transport_locations,title,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL', new TransportLocationIsInactive],
```

I want to run my custom rule before unique check

```
'unique:transport_locations,title,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL'
```

The problem is it always runs a unique check first and returns "The location name has already been taken." :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order

```php
'title' => [
    'required', // 1
    'min:3',    // 2
    new TransportLocationIsInactive, // 3
    'unique:transport_locations,title,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL', // 4
],
```